# Python: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument for no reason

Tags: python

My python script has to write something to file. Code looks like this:

```
with open('last.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(val))
```

In my machine it works fine, but in Windows Server where it has to be in prod, some strange message occured:

```
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
Exception ignored in sys.unraisablehook: <built-in function unraisablehook>
```

Then I put that code in try-except block and when error occured again it says:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
Exception ignored in sys.unraisablehook: <built-in function unraisablehook>
```

Why could this happen? I have no idea and all my project stuck in this error. By the way it doesn't occur everytime, but rarely, even though I have to solve problem and any help would be appreciated

EDIT:
This part of code is inside of function `def write_last(val)`. This function called in loop; `write_last(i+pos)` The `pos` variable is gotten as argument when running script. Also this function can be called outside of loop, as `write_last(k+pos)` `k` variable here is last value of `i` variable from loop, because there could be cases when loop needed to end urgently. And `write_last` code:

```
def write_last(val):
    if working_mod == 2:
        try:
            with open('last.txt', 'w') as f:
                f.write(str(val))
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'file work exception:')#this was temporary solution
            print(e)
```

Variable `working_mod` is also taken as argument when script is executed

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has a reason.

Comment: Yes, it has, but I don't see any leads to find it

Comment: Maybe if you showed the actual code you want help with, you might get better results.

Comment: Actually main code is too big and it doesn't do any other stuff with files except than logging periodically calling open(log_file, 'a') and writing one line.

Comment: But there is code that *is* relevant that you haven't posted (i.e. what is `val`?  *How* did you "put that code in try-except block"?)

Comment: Edited question, explained as much as possible